Cannot invoke org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.RelationalPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(Object)
I keep getting this exception when persisting/inserting a new entity using Spring Data JDBC. What is wrong with my entity?

I already have the version field without final in the audit metadata.

I checked the constructor and properties of the entity to ensure
they align with Spring Data JDBC’s.


This is the exception that I am facing
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.RelationalPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(Object)" because "persistentEntity" is null
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlParametersFactory.getParameterSource(SqlParametersFactory.java:235) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlParametersFactory.lambda$getParameterSource$2(SqlParametersFactory.java:251) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:320) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity.doWithAll(PersistentEntity.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlParametersFactory.getParameterSource(SqlParametersFactory.java:238) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlParametersFactory.forUpdate(SqlParametersFactory.java:98) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.update(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:132) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.updateWithoutVersion(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:338) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeUpdateRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:121) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:93) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$executeSave$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:61) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.SaveBatchingAggregateChange.forEachAction(SaveBatchingAggregateChange.java:64) ~[spring-data-relational-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.executeSave(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:61) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.performSave(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:505) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:171) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:69) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:359) ~[spring-aop-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:515) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:284) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:752) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:174) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:149) ~[spring-data-commons-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:380) ~[spring-tx-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ezycorp.eve.application.AdminController.createMerchant(AdminController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:257) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:986) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]


Below are my java classes

public class MerchantId extends EntityId<String> {
    public MerchantId(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}

public class MerchantKeyId extends EntityId<Integer> {

    public MerchantKeyId(Integer id) {
        super(id);
    }
}

public class BalanceId extends EntityId<Integer> {
    public BalanceId(Integer id) {
        super(id);
    }
}


public class AuditMetadata {

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant updatedAt;

    @Version
    private int version=0;
//omitted getters and setters
}

public enum DashboardPermission {
    DP1,
    DP2
}

public enum PaymentGateway {
    PG1,
    PG2
}

@Table("merchant")
public class Merchant {

    @Id
    private  MerchantId id;

    private  String name;
    
    private  MerchantKeyId merchantKeyId;

    private  String username;

    private  String password;

    private  boolean enabled;

    @Embedded(onEmpty = USE_EMPTY)
    private  Collection<DashboardPermission> dashboardPermissions;
    
    private  BalanceId balanceId;

    private  PaymentGateway paymentGateway;

    private  String webhookUrl;

    @Embedded(onEmpty = USE_NULL)
    private final AuditMetadata auditMetadata = new AuditMetadata();

    @PersistenceCreator
    public Merchant(
            MerchantId merchantId,
            String name,
            String username,
            String password,
            List<DashboardPermission> dashboardPermissions,
            PaymentGateway paymentGateway,
            MerchantKeyId merchantKeyId,
            BalanceId balanceId

    ) {
        this.id = merchantId;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled=true;
        this.dashboardPermissions = dashboardPermissions;
        this.merchantKeyId=merchantKeyId;
        this.balanceId=balanceId;
        this.paymentGateway=paymentGateway;
        this.webhookUrl="";
    }

//omitted getters
}

Added my converters
@WritingConverter
public class IdConverter implements Converter<EntityId<?>,Object> {
    @Override
    public Object convert(EntityId<?> source) {
        return source.getId();
    }
}

@WritingConverter
public class DashboardPermissionConverter implements Converter<Collection<DashboardPermission>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Collection<DashboardPermission> source) {

        return source.stream().map(Enum::name)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected List<?> userConverters() {
        return Arrays.asList(new IdConverter(),
                new DashboardPermissionConverter());
    }
}




Given this happens deep inside Spring itself, I guess this might be a bug in Spring, but without a [mre] that is hard to be sure of.

If you don't have a custom conversion registered for MerchantId id;
@Id
private  MerchantId id;

Won't work with Spring Data JDBC.
Not sure if it is causing the problem you are seeing, but it will fail.
If this is not the cause of your problem, remove stuff from your reproducer, until you can pin point, what is causing your trouble.
For starters remove all the web stuff and make a proper test.
Also remove as many properties as possible, to simplify the problem.

Sorry I forgot to include my converters. I already have them for my entity ids

In that case: create a minimal reproducer and create a Gihub Issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues
